# working with std::bitset

Tags: c++, std, bitset

There is a class definition and some bool functions which test some attributes

```
  class MemCmd
  {
      friend class Packet;
      public:
        enum Command
        {
          InvalidCmd,
          ReadReq,
          ReadResp,
          NUM_MEM_CMDS
        };
      private:
        enum Attribute
        {
          IsRead,         
          IsWrite,             
          NeedsResponse,  
          NUM_COMMAND_ATTRIBUTES
        };

        struct CommandInfo
        {
          const std::bitset<NUM_COMMAND_ATTRIBUTES> attributes;
          const Command response;
          const std::string str;
        };
        static const CommandInfo commandInfo[];
      private:
        bool
        testCmdAttrib(MemCmd::Attribute attrib) const
        {
          return commandInfo[cmd].attributes[attrib] != 0;
        }
      public:
        bool isRead() const         { return testCmdAttrib(IsRead); }
        bool isWrite() const        { return testCmdAttrib(IsWrite); }
        bool needsResponse() const  { return testCmdAttrib(NeedsResponse); }
  };
```

The question is how can I set `NeedsResponse` to true or false prior to calling  `needsResponse()`

Please note that `attributes` is of type `std::bitset`

***UPDATE:***

I wrote this function:

```
void
setCmdAttrib(MemCmd::Attribute attrib, bool flag) 
{
    commandInfo[cmd].attributes[attrib] = flag;   // ERROR
}

void setNeedsResponse(bool flag)   { setCmdAttrib(NeedsResponse, flag); }
```

But I get this error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Comment: You have methods that get the state of the various bits in the `bitset`. Why don't you just add some methods to set the state of the various bits?  Or am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: you are correct. how can i do that? can you give a snippet?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, the hint I'd give is that they'd probably look a lot like `testCmdAttrib()`.

Comment: no it not homework... i am trying to implement my code on a simulator. please see the update in my post

Comment: You're going to struggle to set bits individually, since you declared `attributes` as `const` and hence the whole bitset will need to be initialised in `CommandInfo`'s constructor.

Comment: you mean I have to remove "three" const in `CommandInfo`'s constructor?

Comment: Johnsyweb has the key - but you'll not only need to get rid of the const on `attributes`, but on `commandInfo` as well.

Comment: ok thanks. I think i got it :)

Comment: You haven't provided `CommandInfo::CommandInfo()` in your sample code, the synthesised one may not do what you want. I suspect it doesn't since all three attributes of the `struct` are `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

There are two problems here

1. Data members that are `const` must be initialized in the class constructor.
2. If the members are `const` there is no way to change them later.

So, initialize (at least) the members that are supposed to have a constant value. Remove `const` from the members you intend to change later.